# Count only inputs with value in Laravel 4

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, input

I am trying to create a multiple choice quiz in Laravel,

This is the form the admin uses to insert the questions in the database, so this is not to play the quiz!

I used angular to show and hide answer C D E and F, showing only A and B when the page is loaded.

The idea is to create a for loop, so that I can insert every answer that is not empty.

How do I do this in laravel? I was thinking of `count(Input::get('answer'))` but it doesn't work. And even if it worked it will still count all my answers but not the ones that has a value.

All my answer inputs have the same name.

Please help!

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'QuizController@storeQuestions']) }}

                {{ Form::hidden('id', $quiz->id) }}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Question:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('question', Input::old('question'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer A:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct')  }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer B:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct')  }}
                </div>

                <!-- De '+' krijgt de showInput van de vorige input! -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="add-question-button"><a class="plus-input" ng-click="addAnswer(1)">+</a></span>
                </div>
                <div  ng-show="showInput1"  class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer C:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct')  }}

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="add-question-button"><a ng-show="showInput1" ng-click="addAnswer(2)" class="plus-input">+</a></span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="showInput2" class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer D:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct')  }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="add-question-button"><a ng-show="showInput2" ng-click="addAnswer(3)" class="plus-input">+</a></span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="showInput3" class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer E:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct')  }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <span class="add-question-button"><a ng-show="showInput3" ng-click="addAnswer(4)" class="plus-input">+</a></span>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="showInput4" class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-label">Answer F:</label>
                    {{ Form::text('answer', Input::old('answer'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
                    {{ Form::radio('is-correct') }}
                </div>

                {{ Form::submit('Next question', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block')) }}

                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block">Finish</button>

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(New answer, in response to the revised question)

From the way you've worded the question, I've assumed the maximum number of answers for a question is fixed. Let's further assume you identify those with the letters A to F, as in your example.

Given your "answer" field accepts multiple responses, its name should include square brackets. We can identify each individual answer as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="answer[A]" />
```

We can identify the correct answer by constructing radio buttons of the form:

```
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer" value="A" />
```

Calling `Input::get('answer')` in your controller will return an associative array, where the key is the answer identifier (A to F), and the value is the answer text.

You can use PHP's [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php.co.uk) function to filter out the empty answers.

```
$answers = array_filter(Input::get('answer'));
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, makes perfect sense. I will try this out :)!

Answer (score 1):

The way you've structured the form is a bit confusing.

If this is a multiple choice quiz, then  the answers should be non-editable (labels), and the user should just be required to select the correct answer using a radio button.

In that case, you can set the radio button value to the answer text (or ID, if you're pulling the available answers from a database).

For example:

```
<label>Who was the first man on the moon?</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="man_on_moon" value="Armstrong" /> Neil Armstrong
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="man_on_moon" value="Aldrin" /> Buzz Aldrin
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="man_on_moon" value="Hanks" /> Tom Hanks
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is the form to insert the questions in the database so that later on the user can play the quiz. I should've explained that in my question. Will edit it now.